# Table border-color not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, colors, border

Here is the page: www.igniteye.co.uk.
The border is white in every other browser but IE shows no color. A border is shown but it looks transparent. Why is this not working?

By the way, if you validate the page you will get a lot of errors but none of them are actual errors as the pieces of code causing these are social media links which were copied and pasted from Google, Facebook, and Twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you are applying the border to the `tr`. Targeting the `td` inside will yield much better results.

Comment: Thanks, but now something else freaky is going on, it seems to be showing a gap where the top border would be expected to be if I wanted a top border

Comment: got it! just needed to add border collapse. thanks for your help!